# Error When Installing Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime-error, eclipse-installer

So I've been trying to install eclipse and whenever I run the installer, select Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers, and click install, I get an error message:

```
[2020-11-14 14:18:04] An error was detected while performing the engine operation and the changes are being rolled back. See the log for details.
[2020-11-14 14:18:04] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:291)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:551)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:343)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:899)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3828)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3756)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3737)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3630)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1343)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$33(SimpleVariablePage.java:1211)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1156)
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context was:(profile=C__Users_Joachim_eclipse_jee-2020-09_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 Error reading signed content.
  java.io.IOException: Exception in opening zip file: C:\Users\Joachim\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.buildship.branding_3.1.4.v20200326-1743.jar
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3828)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3756)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3737)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3630)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1343)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$33(SimpleVariablePage.java:1211)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1156)
  Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Joachim\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.buildship.branding_3.1.4.v20200326-1743.jar
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3828)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3756)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3737)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3630)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1343)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$33(SimpleVariablePage.java:1211)
    ... 1 more
```

I've already tried disabling mirror but it still didn't work.
If anyone could tell me what's going on and how I could fix the issue, I would really appreciate it.
 Thanks!

Comment: You could try to maybe download Eclipse directly from the download [package-page](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/)

Comment: Thanks @wpichl! It worked!
But my question still needs answering :P

Answer (score 0):

Check the below things:

1. JAVA_HOME path is correct:
   `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_***`
2. System variables are correct:
   `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_***\bin`
   `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_***\bin`

This was the issue with me. I re-checked and fixed my mistake.